# phyton flask jinja2 no se encuenta el template

Tags: html, python, flask

Hola estoy comenzando un curso en flask, y un de las primeras aplicaciones básicas tengo un error que no logro solucionar. tengo mi área de trabajo estructurada asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index2.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

y el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código del index es este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Welcome!</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

espero puedan ayuadrme, según el video del curso que estoy viendo y según la documentación oficial esta todo bien organizado, el index.html en la carpeta templates y todo lo demás, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Copie tu código, probé en mi máquina y me funciona a la perfección. ¿No será tu forma de ejecutar el app.py? ¿Como lo ejecutas? ¿Desde la terminal?

Comment: @Blasito ¿Incluido el index2.html?

Comment: @fredyfx, no, corregí esa parte por index.html.

Comment: en ese caso, sigo pensando que al momento de ejecutar hay algo raro.

Comment: también pienso lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

#app = Flask(__name__) #anterior
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates') #Nueva configuración

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') #aqui apuntaba a index2.html

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Documentación de flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/

Comment: ya intente eso, se me paso el detalle lo de index2 es poque hice toda la aplicación desde cero, pero de igual forma con index.html tampoco funciona mi muetra el mismo error.

Comment: desde cero por segunda vez a eso me referia con hacer toda la aplicación desde cero.

Comment: intenta reemplazar las comillas dobles por comillas simples, acabo de actualizar la respuesta :D

Comment: acabo de actualizar la respuesta, espero te sea de utilidad